# What is a front-end for the GCC Compiler?

Tags: linux, compile, gcc, gnu, frontend

From what I know a front-end is a GUI for a program or for a website that has a web application in the "back-end".

I am confused to ses that for the GCC (GNU C Compiler) there are many front-ends but it seems that there are different definitions for "front-end" in this context.

Answer (score 2):

A GCC front end turns code into an intermediate, internal form used by GCC. A GCC back end turns this intermediate, internal form into the final form that the compiler outputs.

So, for example, if you have a C++ front end and a Java front end, you can accept input in C++ and Java. If you have an x86 back end and a MIPS back end, you can produce executables for both x86 and MIPS CPUs.

If you wanted to add Go support to GCC, you'd write a Go front end for GCC. Then you could compile Go code for every platform GCC supports.

If you wanted to add support to GCC for a new CPU, you'd write a new back end for that CPU. Then you could produce code for that CPU using every language GCC supports.

Comment: but i thought java compiles to bytecode that is portable and interpreted

Comment: It does. So Java is both a front end (source code has to be turned into an internal format) and a back end (internal format has to be turned into executable output).

Comment: i though java xode is never turned into executable  but into code that is interpreted by java virtual machine

Comment: @yoyo_fun That's just a matter of definitions. IMO, if you don't need to parse it and can run it and it's not human readable, it's an executable.

Comment: but can java executables made by gcc  be run without installing a java virtual machine?

Comment: @yoyo_fun It depends on how you define "java executable". In theory, GCC could take its Java front end and its x86 back end and produce an executable that would run natively on x86. But you'd still somehow need to provide the services the JVM provides such as memory management.

Comment: My guess is that for Java the GCC only has a Front-end in this case. I doubt the GCC interprets Java Bytecode.